# golang - Main loop in network game

Tags: go

I've only begun tinkering with Go for about a week now, and am quite impressed with it.  However, I'm still having a few issues I can't get my head around yet.

The main problem right now is that while I have the connection handling code working, I want to add a main game loop independent of the connection loop.  How does one do this?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "strconv"
  "time"
  "galaxy"
)

const PORT = 5555

func main() {
  playerFactory := galaxy.NewPlayerFactory()

  server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":" + strconv.Itoa(PORT))
  if server == nil {
    panic("listen failed: " + err.Error() + "\n")
  } else {
    defer server.Close()
  }

  // main loop  
  go func() {
    for {   
      // entity updates
      playerFactory.Update()
    }
  }() // adding this just blocks everything after the goroutine

  // connection handling
  for {
    conn, err := server.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("client error: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
      playerFactory.CreatePlayer(conn)
    }
  }

}
```

With the way it is currently written the main loop runs (this is the part I am trying to add), but the connection handling code gets ignored.  Is this where one uses channels to pass control around?  I'm sure the solution is apparent to a more seasoned Go programmer, I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `playerFactory.Update()` never releases the CPU (for example by blocking on a resource), there is no guarantee for other goroutines to run

You could try to change [GOMAXPROCS](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) but that would depend on your number of CPU and the problem would reappear later with other non blocking goroutines.

And I can't see any reason for a game loop to run without interruption. The most frequent case is when you have to do something at regular interval.

In this case, your code would be

```
  // main loop  
  go func() {
     timer := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
     for now := range timer {   
         // entity updates (you could use now for physic engine calculs)
         // this is called every 100 millisecondes
         playerFactory.Update()
     }
  }()
```

Comment: I removed the time calculations to keep the example simple.  Right now playerFactory.Update() does nothing but print a message (assuming clients are connected).

Again, this loop runs, but the code never seems to reach the connection handling loop which is the part that is confusing me.

Comment: I've just tested the code I gave you : the line following it is executed. Are you sure you're connecting properly ? Are you sure you used the timer properly (for example as I did) ? This is not about time calculations but about blocking until a tick happens (every 100 ms).

Comment: I am not exactly sure what I was doing wrong, but I changed my timer code to yours and now everything works as I was expecting.  Thanks for the help! (Ah ok, your edited comment explains it, got it now).

Comment: Upon further inspection I was just testing things wrong, and everything was actually working correctly.  Thanks again though dystroy.

Comment: I believe that as of Go 1.2, with pre-emptive scheduling, the potential for blocking other goroutines from running should be gone.